# Create points every 20m with GDAL?

Tags: gdal, shapely, linestring, fiona

I have code written in ArcMap which uses the package ArcPy which I cannot use in a stand-alone Python script, but I want to do it with GDAL without ArcMap. Basically it goes through the lines in the shapefile and create points every 20 meters and stores all these points in a new shapefile.

I have tried using the interpolate method in fiona and am just very lost.

Could someone help?

Comment: How about using ogr2ogr with -segmentize http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html?

Comment: Or perhaps better with ogr2ogr with SQLite dialect and function line_interpolate_point http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html.

Answer (score 6):

> I have tried using the interpolate method in fiona and am just very lost.

With [Shapely](http://toblerity.github.com/shapely/manual.html) ([interpolate()](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#linear-referencing-methods)) and [Fiona](http://toblerity.github.com/fiona/manual.html)

```
# open the line shapefile
import fiona
line = fiona.open('line.shp')
# example with the first feature
firstline = line.next()
# transform to shapely geometry
from shapely.geometry import shape, mapping
first = shape(firstline['geometry'])
# length of the LineString
length = first.length
```

[image]

```
# creation of the resulting shapefile
schema = {'geometry': 'Point','properties': {'id': 'int'},}
with fiona.open('result.shp', 'w', 'ESRI Shapefile', schema)  as output:
    # create points every 20 meters along the line
    for distance in range(0,int(length),20):
         point = first.interpolate(distance)   
         output.write({'geometry':mapping(point),'properties': {'id':1}})
```

[image]